# ¿Por qué hay dos representaciones de una barra de navegación diferente para dos códigos html idénticos?

Tags: html, css

Intento construir una barra de navegación que deberia que debería haber tenido este aspecto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero obtengo esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy seguro que utiliso el mismo `html` codigo que el profesor entonces pienso que proviene de archivos css.

Aqui esta el codigo `html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm bg-primary fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>            
    </div>
</nav>
```

Estoy siguiendo un curso Front-End Web UI Frameworks and Tools: Bootstrap 4, sobre Coursera. en particular el [curso sobre componentes CSS de Bootstrap](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bootstrap-4/lecture/agf7J/exercise-video-navbar-and-breadcrumbs).

Una persona llamada MCheli lo hizo bien, usé su código a excepción de los archivos HTML. Tiene una buena salida. [Aqui esta su repositorio GitHub para este ejercicio](https://github.com/MCheli/Full-Stack-Web-Dev-Coursera/tree/master/Front-End%20Web%20UI%20Frameworks%20and%20Tools/Week%202%20-%20Boostrap%20CSS%20Components/conFusion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El css esta bien.
Lo que pasa es que en el video utiliza otra versión de Bootstrap (v4 alpha).

Para arreglar lo que tenias seria cuestión de añadir classe nav en la lista (`<ul class="navbar-nav nav">`)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm bg-primary fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>            
    </div>
</nav>
```

Pero esto esta incompleto. En la propia pagina de bootstrap tienes una buena documentación https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Aquí tienes el resultado:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>            
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! No sé porque no funciona sin esta palabra clave `nav`. ¿Podria funcionar con otra cosa ? ¿Qué significa para el compilador no tenerlo?

Comment: ¿Y como hacer para 1. hacer que la barra me siga cuando me muevo sobre la página y 2. utilisar la misma version de Bootstrap ?

Comment: Para utilizar la version 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start

Comment: Para utlizar la version 4 alpha: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start

Comment: Menu fijo en la version 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement  Y en la version 4 alpha https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#placement. Seria cuestión de añadir la clase .fixed-top en el `<nav class="fixed-top">`